# How can i query the same document id

Tags: flutter

I have a listview.builder and each ListTile displays three fields from a particular document in my firestore collection. What i want to implement is , when that listtile is clicked it should take the user to a page that displays more fields from that same document.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsH1J.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EpvI.jpg)

Comment: please include codes of what you have tried so far

Comment: can i contact you because the code to big @KaushikChandru

Comment: please create a minimum reproducible set of codes so you get more suggestions from everyone.

Comment: i message you on FB

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.